# Add annotations on plot with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, python

I am trying to generate a plot from Python and add annotations (identification of the three phases in the plot, and add separation lines).

I start with a Python plot:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')

A = 1
T1, T2 = 10, 40
D = 2
DT = 10e-3

time = [0]
a,v,p = [0], [0], [0]

t = 0
while t < T1:
    a.append(A)
    v.append(v[-1] + a[-1] * DT)
    p.append(p[-1] + v[-1] * DT)
    time.append(t := t + DT)

while t < T2:
    a.append(0)
    v.append(v[-1] + a[-1] * DT)
    p.append(p[-1] + v[-1] * DT)
    time.append(t := t + DT)

while v[-1] > 0:
    a.append(_a := -D)
    v.append(v[-1] + a[-1] * DT)
    p.append(p[-1] + v[-1] * DT)
    time.append(t := t + DT)

a.append(0)
v.append(0)
p.append(p[-1])
time.append(time[-1])

x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)
y = 2 * np.sin(x)

rc = {
    "xtick.direction": "inout", 
    "ytick.direction": "inout",
    "xtick.major.size": 5, 
    "ytick.major.size": 5, 
}

with plt.rc_context(rc):
    cm = 1/2.54  # centimeters in inches
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, figsize=(19*cm, 10*cm))
    fig.tight_layout(pad=1.0)

    ax[0].plot(time, a)
    ax[1].plot(time, v)
    ax[2].plot(time, p, label='Position')
    
    ax[0].set_ylabel(r'Accélération $\frac{m}{s^2}$')
    ax[1].set_ylabel(r'Vitesse $\frac{m}{s}$')
    ax[2].set_ylabel(r'Position $m$')

    ax[2].set_xlabel(r'Temps $s$')

    for axis in ax:
        axis.grid(True)

    import tikzplotlib

    tikzplotlib.save(sys.argv[1])
```

)

Then I highjack the generated figure by adding the following before the `\end{tikzpicture}`

```
\draw (1.7,3) circle [radius=0.4] node {$1$};
\draw (6,3) circle [radius=0.4] node {$2$};
\draw (10.8,3) circle [radius=0.4] node {$3$};
\draw [line width=0.25mm, red, densely dotted] (5,-5) -- (5,3);
```

Notice that the positions are set by hand (still not find where to place the red dashed line).

Eventually, I generate my picture using LaTeX :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,
    width=12cm,
    height=2.5cm,
    scale only axis=true,
    max space between ticks=25pt,
    try min ticks=5,
    every axis/.style={  
        axis y line=left,
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis line style={thick,->,>=latex, shorten >=-.4cm}
    },
    every axis plot/.append style={thick},
    tick style={black, thick}
}
\tikzset{
    semithick/.style={line width=1.2pt},
}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \input{figure.pgf}
  \caption{Example}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And here is the whole process:

```
$ ./figure.py figure.pgf
$ vi figure.pgf # Done manually for now...
$ latexmk -pdf example.tex
```

So I have two questions:

1. How should I make this process simpler?
2. How should I position my elements on the figure relative to the plot?

Here is the generated picture:

[image]

Comment: Haven't really used `tikzplotlib`, but looking at the docstring there is "`axes.Axes._tikzplotlib_anchors`   This attribute can be set to a list of `((x,y), anchor_name)` tuples. Invisible nodes at the respective location will be created which  can be referenced from outside the axis environment.". I'm guessing that will add `\coordinate`s at the given coordinates. `tikzplotlib` also lets you add stuff and the end of the `tikzpicture` with e.g. `extra_tikzpicture_parameters={\draw [red,dotted] (a) -- (b);}`, which you may be able to combine with the `_tikzplotlib_anchors`.

Comment: One can generate high quality vector graphics with Python+Inkscape, see [here](https://www.alanshawn.com/tech/2021/03/27/matplotlib-latex-style.html). I find it very useful in my work. Basically, set `plt.rcParams['svg.fonttype'] = 'none'` and export the plots as SVG format. In your plot, use LaTeX commands in the annotations, which can be automatically rendered correctly when imported to LaTeX. Then, use the `svg` package from LaTeX to import the SVG files.

Comment: @AlanXiang can you get the LaTeX fonts? TikZ plots are neat, and with arrows on axes.

Comment: @nowox Yes, if you set `plt.rcParams['svg.fonttype'] = 'none'`, save the plot as SVG and import the SVG into LaTeX, all fonts are native LaTeX fonts.